# Confusion about One equality about Marginal likelihood

Tags: statistics

When I checked Wikipedia about Marginal likelihood, I find an equality of the form:
$$
p(a\mid b)=\int p(a\mid c)\cdot p(c\mid b)\,dc
$$
and it's valid because the parameter c is marginalized/integrated out. However, when I tried proving its validity by actually performing integration and sum&product rules of probability, I failed... And I just can't figure out how that marginalization really works.

Could someone explain it in details and show me the procedures of deduction?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458935/combining-conditional-probabilities

Comment: basically it is not necessarily true unless $p(a|c) = p(a|c,b)$.